# How to extract HTML produced by PrimeNG p-dataTable

Tags: angular, primeng-datatable

I've a page that uses PrimeNG p-dataTable. I need to export the data to Excel and PDF. For the excel, I'm using **EPPLUS** library. For the PDF, I've an online service that works fine as well. However, the PDF requires to submit HTML markups.

Before starting duplicating the work I obtain by using PrimeNG p-dtaTable, I'd like to know whether it's possible to capture all the markup produced then submit it to the service.

Thanks for helping